# I have Delivery Plans installed in Azure DevOps (as an extension via Marketplace) but cannot see in Boards Menu

Tags: azure-devops, project

I have Delivery Plans installed in Azure DevOps (as an extension via Marketplace) but cannot see in Boards Menu as I followed these instructions but still cannot view even though it says already installed,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/plan-track-work?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process

If this cannot be done , is there a next best alternative?

Comment: Hi MrRabbit, How about this issue? Does my answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this extension: [Delivery Plans](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-plans) has been installed in your organization, please make sure that it is **enabled** by reference to this doc: [Uninstall or disable extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/uninstall-disable-extensions?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

In addition, please make sure that you meet below Prerequisites by reference to this doc: [Review team Delivery Plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops&tabs=plans), then can use this extension without any issues.

[image]